# Implementing piecewise convolutional neural networks / piecewise max pooling

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, conv-neural-network

I'm currently trying to implement a piecewise max pooling operation in Tensorflow, as described [here](http://tsong.me/blog/pcnn/). Given a sentence, I want to divide it to three different portions and max pool all of those portions separately, so that I'd end up with 3 different values instead of 1.

More concretely, I have a tensor `training` of shape `[batch_len, 1, sentence_len, feature_len]`. I also have another tensor `splits` of shape `[batch_len, 2]`, where the first element of any row is the index to split off the first portion, and the second element is the index to split off the last portion. I want to index the `training` tensor in a way that divides it into tree parts based on the value index values provided in the `splits` tensor.

We cannot simply index the `training` tensor using the other tensor, as we have different lengths for the first, second, and third portions for different examples. I *could* loop through all the training data and do it that way, but that would be horribly inefficient. I want to make this as efficient as possible.

Note: since they will be max pooled, I'm fine with having 3 different tensors of shape `[batch_len, 1, sentence_len, feature_len]`, where in the first tensor, only the elements in the first portion of each sentence has values, and the others have zero. The second tensor would only have values in the middle part, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploring and implementing [PCNN](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1203) model leads me to the same problem: splitting borders (positions of entities) may vary in input.

To implement piecewise max pooling, the combination of `tf.split` calls for obtaining three parts and `tf.pad`call for each part were used. Then we apply `tf.nn.max_pool` to perform max pooling for each padded part.

[Here](https://github.com/nicolay-r/sentiment-pcnn) is a tensorflow implementation of PCNN model as an application for sentiment classification. [Here](https://github.com/nicolay-r/sentiment-pcnn/blob/7dc58bf34eab609aebe258dc1157010653994920/networks/pcnn/pcnn_core.py#L48) is an exact position of the network description in code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to TensorFlow and Keras, so correct me if I'm wrong.

From what I understand from your question, this seems to be a straightforward case of using the 'pool_size' argument in the max_pooling2d layer of tensorflow.

If you want to go for the easiest approach, ensure that all your sentences are padded to the same length, and since you want three portions( I assume you meant three when you said 'divides it into tree parts' ) over which you want max pooling to be done, just set the 'pool_size' and 'strides' argument to sent_length/3.

However, if you want to use the indices specified in the other tensor, I suggest that don't use tensors, but use normal integers to represent the indices, and then define a Lambda layer to split your sentence into 3 parts based on the indices, and apply global max pooling on each part. This code might help understand it better :

```
part_1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :first_index, :])
part_2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, first_index:second_index, :])
part_3 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, second_index:, :])
```

And then do max pooling on each part with appropriate filter sizes equalling the length of each part. If a simple len() doesn't give you the length, you can get the length from calling the shape (using the appropriate index of the shape).